2021 Q2 Activity Support Proposals
I've been thinking about how to use our Q2 activity support from TLG. Last summer, we compiled proposals from a number of users for the use of this support. That seemed to drive great content and was well-received by the community, so I'd like to do that again.
I will be accepting proposals here until Friday, June 11th. I'm very open to input from anyone on this process. However, because I have to report back to TLG how these sets were used, final decisions over what is approved will be at my discretion. Important factors for me will be community feedback for a user's proposal (via comments and votes here), as well as the quality of content that a user generally creates.
Users submitting proposals must meet the following requirements:

You must have earned at least 200 rep in 2021 or 1k rep total.
You may not resell these sets. This is a TLG requirement.
The requested set(s) need to be prominently featured in at least one question. Your question(s) should be part of the proposal to receive your set(s). The question will likely be self-answered by you and should be tagged as activity-support. Alternatively, I'm open to other non-Q&A creative uses of these sets as well (social media campaigns, etc) as long as they serve the core purpose of our community.
You must be committed to completing your proposed work within 1 month of receiving your sets.

For those of you unaware, TLG has updated the way activity support works this year, so we can now request the following each year:

3 total support requests (Q1, Q2, Q3/Q4 submitted by October)
667 EUR per request
10 items total, up to 5 copies of the same set
Maximum of 5 addresses on the request

I look forward to seeing all of your creative ideas here.
Update:
We're moving forward with both of the proposals below.

Out of curiosity would the activity support scheme apply to answering existing questions on the site? I am really proud of the fact the site has such a low rate of unanswered questions and there are some questions here that might be interesting to answer

@Ambo100 Absolutely. I'm not sure what questions you have in mind, but it would be excellent to deliver a great answer to an unanswered question.

I was curious about this question but I found what I think would be a good enough answer without needing to get the set. I was also curious about your question about road plates but I am not sure if I could find an answer even if I had the set.

I'm trying to find more ways to demonstrate and showcase LEGO building in our community. I'd like to propose that each interested participant this quarter receive a copy of 80022 in addition to their own proposed set. The set includes multiple copies of the following new elements:
72869 (9x black, 2x purple)

73230 (4x)

70681 (8x)

Interested participants would each share an answer for a question such as "What new building opportunities are created using the new 1x1 brick with axle hole?". I would expect answers to include building ideas, table scraps demonstrating techniques, and/or MOCs prominently using the new elements. This would be similar in concept to what New Elementary and other communities have done with their parts festivals. These questions would be asked one at a time over several months to create more content over a longer period of time and to not overwhelm participants.
I know that not everyone is a builder, so folks can opt out of the new parts challenge and still put forth a proposal.

I like this idea. 80022 set is priced at 99.99€. If we get maximum number (5) of ideas selected and everyone chose to receive this set, we have just 167.05 euro left to split.

@Alex That's a good point. If we get 5 people interested, it might make sense to pick a less expensive set for some of them to explore. I also considered 41449 for the new curved window element.

I know this is possibly too much to ask for, but I’d like to review set 10278 Police Station (EUR 179.99) with a copy of 60304 Road Plates (EUR 19.99) to answer the question: what are different ways I can use the new road plates for my modular city?
If both together are too much, I am okay in dropping 60304 as I can easily obtain a copy myself.



I love this idea, but it would be tough to justify 200 EUR if we get other great submissions. New Elementary did cover this to some extent already in their review: https://www.newelementary.com/2020/12/lego-city-review-mocs-60304-road-plates.html

I’ve got some additonal ideas to what newelementary suggested, but I’ll check and possibly put in another suggestion for a review.
